# Risk of specific changes to the "Trusted" security zone

Tags: windows-10, trust

Our EDI VAN provides software to transmit sensitive customer and business data between our ERP and their website. This software requires that I add several URLs (including one plain HTTP) to the "Trusted" security zone on Windows 10. It also requires that I enable "Display mixed content", "Access data sources across domains", and "Don't prompt for client certificate selection when only one certificate exists" for that zone.

What are the security implications of these changes? Are any of them clearly unnecessary security risks that I should warn my managers about? I already have a low opinion of our EDI VAN, so my bias may be fueling my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

An EDI VAN is a secure outsourced network where EDI documents can be exchanged between business partners. Your company is provided with a "mailbox" or alternate means from which EDI documents are sent and received, similar to traditional paper based mail (snail mail). The “value added” part of the mailbox are often services like mail notifications, inspect, authentication, and validating the message.  Messages should be tracked and recorded for auditing purposes, as well as other services available through VANs, such as backup and recovery, mapping, compliance and more.

For everything to be in order you must have high trust in the EDI VAN provider and / or be able to make sure it handles security in a sufficiently good manner. Otherwise, you may end up with something being compromised.

Setting everything as "trusted" is definitely not a good security practice. That would practically allow that software to do anything and transmit anything across your infrastructure (given the other settings).

Instead, you should ask the provider what ports or other limited settings are specifically needed to enable correct communication between the software and its destinations. Mixed content means the connection is not required to be secure, which is a big risk (you will transmit data that is not encrypted).

Therefore, you should definitely determine how trusted that provider is and warn your company in regard to security.

Comment: I don't think their software is malicious, just badly designed. (In many ways.) To be clear, do these setting changes required by their software make the system vulnerable to other software that might be malicious? Can you be specific about how? I know very little about Windows security, and the people I need to convince know even less.

Comment: It does not have to be malicious, but many large companies have really bad and insecure software, most banks included. So don't count on their security, do your own.

Comment: Agreed. I've seen a payment gateway written by a single junior developer working alone, a very high rep SO user whose profile boasted of working for a major bank spouting off absolute nonsense, and my own credit union's Android app which constantly crashes. But in a practical sense, is there anything I can do beyond pressuring my managers to dump this insecure VAN? I hate the VAN for many other reasons, but I need something concrete to take to management. (Apparently "we're dumping 100 hours a week into something that should be done by computers" isn't enough.)

Comment: If you want to convince management to change a bad system, usually you have to prove 2 things: that you found a better one and that the new proposed one is not more expensive than the current one.

Comment: Yes, this question is about cost -- potential or likely costs of a seemingly insecure configuration. I'm looking for something concrete like, "malicious software could eavesdrop on EDI traffic", "this would expose our browsers to XSS attacks on entirely unrelated sites", etc.